# Keep Outlook App pane open

Tags: outlook, office365-apps

I am developing an Outlook App. That works fine, the app works perfect but we would like to keep the pane open when a user changes the email.

After googleing for some time I couldn't find a solution for this problem. Can you guys help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible in the current version of Office.

Answer (score 0):

it is possible in outlook 2016. It is called pinnable Taskpane. You can see detail

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/exchangedev/2017/01/26/pinnable-taskpane-in-outlook-2016/